# How to understand this GNU C inline assembly macro for PowerPC stwbrx

Tags: c, assembly, embedded, endianness, powerpc

This is basically to perform swap for the buffers while transferring a message buffer. This statement left me puzzled (because of my unfamiliarity with the embedded assembly code in c). This is a power pc instruction

```
#define ASMSWAP32(dest_addr,data) __asm__ volatile ("stwbrx %0, 0, %1" : : "r" (data), "r" (dest_addr))
```

Comment: Please change the tags to include your compiler and architecture. `embedded` and `volatile` are not appropriate, I think, so you could replace them.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_stwbrx_stbrx.htm this tells you all you need to know about the instruction

Comment: check out [inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `#define ASMSWAP32(dest_addr,data)` ...

This part should be clear

> `__asm__ volatile (` ... `: : "r" (data), "r" (dest_addr))`

This is the actual inline assembly:

Two values are passed to the assmbly code; no value is returned from the assembly code (this is the colons after the actual assembly code).

Both parameters are passed in registers (`"r"`). The expression `%0` will be replaced by the register that contains the value of `data` while the expression `%1` will be replaced by the register that contains the value of `dest_addr` (which will be a pointer in this case).

The `volatile` here means that the assembly code has to be executed at this point and cannot be moved to somewhere else.

So if you use the following code in the C source:

```
ASMSWAP(&a, b);
```

... the following assembler code will be generated:

```
# write the address of a to register 5 (for example)
...
# write the value of b to register 6
...
stwbrx 6, 0, 5
```

So the first argument of the `stwbrx` instruction is the value of `b` and the last argument is the address of `a`.

> `stwbrx x, 0, y`

This instruction writes the value in register `x` to the address stored in register `y`; however it writes the value in "reverse endian" (on a big-endian CPU it writes the value "little endian".

The following code:

```
uint32 a;
ASMSWAP32(&a, 0x12345678);
```

... should therefore result in `a = 0x78563412`.

Comment: `volatile` isn't as strong as you make it sound.  Without a `"memory"` clobber, it doesn't totally prevent reordering with other code.  It means the asm statement has side-effects and has to run exactly as many times as the source says, not just when the compiler wants to produce its outputs.

Comment: Worth pointing out that `0` (not `%0`) is the PPC zero-register, so adding it to the address produces the address.

Answer (score 7):

Besides being unsafe because of a bug, this macro is also less efficient than what the compiler will generate for you.

---

`stwbrx` = [store word byte-reversed](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.alangref/idalangref_stwbrx_stbrx.htm).  The `x` stands for indexed.

You don't need inline asm for this in GNU C, where you can use [`__builtin_bswap32`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html) and let the compiler emit this instruction for you.

```
void swapstore_asm(int a, int *p) {
    ASMSWAP32(p, a);
}

void swapstore_c(int a, int *p) {
    *p = __builtin_bswap32(a);
}
```

Compiled with gcc4.8.5 `-O3 -mregnames`, we get identical code from both functions  [(Godbolt compiler explorer)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23define+ASMSWAP32(dest_addr,data)+__asm__+volatile+(%22stwbrx+%250,+0,+%251%22+:+:+%22r%22+(data),+%22r%22+(dest_addr))%0A%0Avoid+swapstore(int+a,+int+*p)+%7B%0A++++ASMSWAP32(p,+a)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Avoid+swapstore_c(int+a,+int+*p)+%7B%0A++++*p+%3D+__builtin_bswap32(a)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:30.51212938005391,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppcg48,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'0',trim:'1'),libs:!(),options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-Wall+-O3+-mregnames',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'PowerPC+gcc+4.8.5+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:65.61546286876907,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+PowerPC+gcc+4.8.5',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:34.38453713123093,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:69.4878706199461,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
swapstore:
    stwbrx %r3, 0, %r4
    blr
swapstore_c:
    stwbrx %r3,0,%r4
    blr
```

But with a more complicated address (storing to `p[off]`, where `off` is an integer function arg), the compiler knows how to use both register inputs, while your macro forces the compiler to have the address in a single register:

```
void swapstore_offset(int a, int *p, int off) {
     = __builtin_bswap32(a);
}

swapstore_offset:
    slwi %r5,%r5,2              # *4 = sizeof(int)
    stwbrx %r3,%r4,%r5          # use an indexed addressing mode, with both registers non-zero
    blr

swapstore_offset_asm:
    slwi %r5,%r5,2
    add %r4,%r4,%r5            # extra instruction forced by using the macro
    stwbrx %r3, 0, %r4
    blr
```

BTW, if you're having trouble understanding GNU C inline asm templates, looking at the compiler's asm output can be a useful way to see what gets substituted in.  See [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output) for more about reading compiler asm output.

---

**Also note that this macro is buggy: it's missing a `"memory"` clobber for the store**.  And yes, you still need that with `asm volatile`.  The compiler doesn't assume that `*dest_addr` is modified unless you tell it, so it could hoist a non-volatile load of `*dest_addr` ahead of this insn, or more likely to be a real problem, sink a store after it.  (e.g. if you zeroed a buffer before storing to it with this, the compiler might actually zero *after* this instruction.)

Instead of a `"memory"` clobber (and also leaving out `volatile`), you could tell the compiler *which* memory location you modify with a `=m" (*dest_addr)` operand, either as a dummy operand or with a constraint on the addressing mode so you could use it as `reg+reg`.  (IDK PPC well enough to know what `"=m"` usually expands to.)

In most cases this bug won't bite you, but it's still a bug.  Upgrading your compiler version or using link-time optimization could maybe make your program buggy with no source-level changes.

This kind of thing is why https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm

See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inline-assembly/info.